# negative lookahead regex on elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to do a negative lookahead on an elasticsearch query, 
the regex is:

```
(?!.*charge)(?!.*encode)(?!.*relate).*night.*
```

the text that I'm matching against is:

> credited back on night stay, still having issues with construction. 
>   causing health issues due to a chemical being sprayed and causes eyes
>   to irritated.

I didn't get any lucky. Can someone give a hand?

ES query:

```
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "regexp": {
                "message": {
                  "value": "(?!.*charge)(?!.*encode)(?!.*relate).*night.*",
                  "flags_value": 65535
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "resNb": {
            "query": "462031152161",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What are the expected matches?..

Comment: @nicael the whole text message should since I have "night" match and none of the negatives groups.

Comment: (I don't know elasticsearch) If you make night a capture group, does it work? `(?!.*charge)(?!.*encode)(?!.*relate)(.*night.*)`

Comment: It'll probably be more efficient to use a boolean query that looks for `night` and not `charge`/`encode`/`relate`.

Comment: But, your issue is probably the fact that `message` is being analyzed and the words aren't exactly as expected. I had a lot of issues with that at one point when I was evaluating a combined PK (`#-#`) and the analyzer was breaking it into pieces (`#` and `#`) so my regex (looking for `-`) wouldn't match.

Comment: @ReginaldoSoares as far as I know, lookbehind does not support variable length.

Comment: Try `"value": "~(charge|encode|relate)night~(charge|encode|relate)", "flags" : "ALL"`. Or `.*night.*&~.*(charge|encode|relate).*`

Comment: Please test my suggested pattern and let me know if they work, so that I could explain in an answer how they work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you so much it worked, please place the explanation.

Comment: Ok, writing it, hold on

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Solution

You can solve the issue with either of the two:

```
"value": "~(charge|encode|relate)night~(charge|encode|relate)",
```

or

```
.*night.*&~(.*(charge|encode|relate).*)
```

With an optional (since it is ON *by default*)

```
"flags" : "ALL"
```

## How does it work?

In common NFA regular expressions, you usually have negative lookarounds that help restrict a more generic pattern (those that look like `(?!...)` or `(?<!...)`). However, in ElasticSearch, you need to use specific [*optional operators*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_optional_operators).

The `~` (tilde) is the *complement* that is *used to negate an atom right after it. An atom is either a single symbol or a group of subpatterns/alternatives inside a group.

NOTE that all ES patterns are anchored at the start and end of string by default, you never need to use `^` and `$` common in Perl-like and .NET, and other NFAs.

Thus,

- `~(charge|encode|relate)` - matches any text from the start of the string other than `charge`, `encode` and `relate`
- `night` - matches the word `night`
- `~(charge|encode|relate)` - matches any text other than either of the 3 substrings up to the end of string.

In an NFA regex like Perl, you could write that pattern using a [**tempered greedy token**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
/^(?:(?!charge|encode|relate).)*night(?:(?!charge|encode|relate).)*$/
```

The second pattern is trickier: common NFA regexes usually do not jump from location to location when matching, thus, lookaheads anchored at the start of text are commonly used. Here, using an *INTERSECTION* we can just use 2 patterns, where one will be matching the string *and* the second one should also match the string.

- `.*night.*` - match the whole line (as `.` matches any symbol but a newline, else, use `(.|\n)*`) with `night` in it
- `&` - *and*
- `~(.*(charge|encode|relate).*)` - the line that does not have `charge`, `encode` and `relate` substrings in it.

An NFA Perl-like regex would look like

```
/^(?!.*(charge|encode|relate)).*night.*$/
```

Comment: can you help with this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783196/regexp-character-doesnt-work-in-es-dsl-query-even-on-type-set-as-keyword-i?noredirect=1#comment90568357_51783196

Comment: can you help with this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783196/negative-lookahead-regexp-doesnt-work-in-es-dsl-query

Answer (score -1):

You didn't use an **anchor** for your lookaheads. Try using "^" at the beginning of the pattern and it should work.

Comment: Elasticsearch regexps are always anchors, the `^` and `$` are not part of the ES regex syntax

Comment: [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html#regexp-unsupported-operators) states that the anchor operators (`^`and `$`) are not supported.