# other possible way of writing some regexp

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have regex something like below:

```
f04((?!z).)*
```

Requirements :

1.)`f04` matches the characters f04 literally (case sensitive)

2.) Assert that the Regex below does not match, `z` matches the character `z` literally (case sensitive)

3.) `.` matches any character

What can be the other possible way to write this particular regexp with the same requirements as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one alternative:

```
f04(.*?)(?=z|$)
```

### Demo

This pattern will match `f04` followed by anything until either hitting the first letter `z`, *or* until hitting the end of the entire string, should a `z` never occur.

Your current approach uses a tempered dot, but both patterns should behave similarly.

Comment: Can you plz help me on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783196/regexp-character-doesnt-work-in-es-dsl-query-even-on-type-set-as-keyword-i

Comment: i just tried to do something like this ^(f04ba)[^z]+?$ instead of this f04((?!z).)* to avoid answers with z; and it did work. Does this thing gives you any hint that why ! in the regexp query doesnt give any results in my elastic search case?

Comment: @zubug55 Yes, it implies that Elastic Search does not support lookarounds.

Comment: you know what i think i found the solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645755/negative-lookahead-regex-on-elasticsearch -> so i have to do something like this -> .*f04.*&~(.*z.*)