# Lucene Regex for alphanumeric match but not all numeric

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene

I want to find the alphanumeric words in lucene automata regex but not entirely numeric and even not entirely alphabets.
I have tried

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10})&(.*[0-9].*))
```

but this returns all numeric words also
So i tried to negate all numeric like below but it does not work

```
(^[0-9])(([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10})&(.*[0-9].*))
```

Input String:

1. DL200, dal2 , 700091

Expected output:
DL200 and dal2

but it should not return 700091

Comment: Could you please provide some examples of inputs & outputs?

Comment: @ChristianBaumann i have added input and ouput

Comment: It's always non numeric followed by numeric?

Comment: no...can be in any sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the `JvdV` answer and with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38665819/9758194, I was able to get the desired output

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10})&(.*[0-9].*))&~([0-9]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't know much about lucene regex flavor, but a little research tought me that it does **not** support `PCRE` library, however some standard operators are supported. I found that it does not include lookarounds *nor* word boundaries. Have a look at the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html).

Either way, to overcome the lack of support on lookarounds I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38665819/9758194) older SO post to use `~` instead. Furthermore, I see you can use the `&` operator to check if the string matches ***multiple*** patterns.

This makes for the assumption the following pattern might work for you:

```
~[0-9]+&~[^0-9]+&[A-Za-z0-9]{2,10}
```

- `~[0-9]+` - Negate a string made of numbers only.
- `&`
- `~[^0-9]+` - Negate a string made of non-numbers only.
- `&`
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{2,10}` - Matches a string that is made out of 2 to 10 alphanumeric characters.

Comment: your answer helped. I added the answer with regex I used

Comment: @happy, there you go. Nice answer. I missed that you wanted to avoid a fully alphabetical string too. In that case, maybe `~[0-9]+&~[^0-9]+&[A-Za-z0-9]{2,10}` works?